# Test a view from a test project without mocking?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

How can I test my view from my test project without the use of mocking? I've tried all kinds of things. Making an ASP .NET Application Host via a MarshalByRefObject and using its ViewToString method. I've also tried instantiating a ViewPage object dynamically, with no luck.

```
Test method Fablelane.WebApplication.Tests.UseCases.CreateNewSchoolAsAdministrator threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.VirtualPath.GetCacheKey()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, ref Boolean keyFromVPP)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName)
at Fablelane.WebApplication.Tests.Extensions.ControllerExtensions.RenderPartialToString(ControllerBase controller, String partialName, Object model, RouteData routeData) in ControllerExtensions.cs: line 28
at Fablelane.WebApplication.Tests.UseCases.InvokeView(Controller controller, ViewResult result) in UseCases.cs: line 104
at Fablelane.WebApplication.Tests.UseCases.CreateNewSchoolAsAdministrator() in UseCases.cs: line 226
```

That error is when I use the instantiation method.

When I try to do the Application Host solution, it fails with a serialization exception saying that a property can't be serialized.

I'm stuck - what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is in your UI layer and you simply unit test your UI layer, mocking everything from the service layer and up which your controller/view is using.

You UI layer doesn't require integration tests as your test team testing that your use cases (functionality) are implemented correctly will let you know if the page can't load.

Your business logic usually is found in a separate layer, for example your service layer.
This is where integration tests are most commonly found, between your service and data layer.

Rather than trying to work around environment issues why not stick with what works? Unit Tests for UI layer and Unit as well as Integration Tests for the Service Layer.

In addition for automated browser testing you can use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or similar.

Comment: I don't have a testing team. We're like 2 persons working on this at the moment.

Comment: Regardless, you still have to run your web site to ensure you have added all the functionality. That is where you notice if a page doesn't load. You don't have to write integration tests at all if you are a team of 2 but if you decide to write them I still would only write them service layer up as the UI is already tested by you validating functionality you added.

Comment: I'm not worried about the page loading. Often errors occur which are first found when you DO something special on the page. Every time such an error occurs, I program a test for it.

Comment: I suppose to try and answer you question `How can I test my view from my test project without the use of mocking?` I would not recommend doing that as said. I'd recommend you writing unit tests against the controller mocking the other layers and writing your integration test (no mocking) against the layer where your Business Logic is contained in. It's cleaner, the intent of the test is clear and it is less messy. If you don't like to mock that's is fine, it's just messier I guess.